# Nexus S after update to JB doesn't show callers name

Tags: contacts, calls, caller-id

I've installed the update to Jelly Bean on my Nexus S and when someone calls, it shows only the phone number of the contact (the contact was saved in the contant list) and not the name of the person.

When I updated to ICS some months ago, the phone number was there for few seconds (like 5 seconds or so) before the name actually appeared.

What's causing this and what can I do about it?

Something tells me that it has to do something with performance of the phone. On Ginger Bread it was all good. On ICS it took some time to show the name and now it doesn't show at all. The phone is incredibly slow and almost out of memory the whole time.

EDIT: When the call ends I can see in the history of calls that it shows the name of the contact.

Comment: Are you syncing your contacts to your Google account?  If so, can you verify that they are synced properly?

Comment: I don't know how to check that, but looking at the google contacts web all the contacts are there and syncing is enabled in the phone.

Comment: Edited Q - it shows the contact's name when I look into the history of calls after the call.